# Asp.Net Impersonation over a VPN

Tags: asp.net, impersonation, vpn

I'm doing a spot of development from home over a VPN. The project is an Asp.Net 2.0 (Using 3.5 SP1) app that uses impersonation.  The account that is impersonated is on the domain at work but when ever I attempt to run the app I get the following error:

> 'Logon failure: unknown user name or
>   bad password.'

The impersonation is required for the app to access the SQL Database located at work. The connection string fully specifies the Server + domain.

Any ideas what it could be? or resources I could look at?

Cheers
Tony

Comment: Does this work when you are at the office?

Comment: Yea works spot on, two other people have almost the same setup but it works for them...

Answer (score 0):

Does the impersonation have access via the VPN server as well? Also, is your VPN server using IPSEC?